# Javascript: Check when a function is called and from where

Tags: javascript

I have a problem on a website where for certain clients the page scrolls by itself. I suspect is a `scrollTop` function somewhere being triggered by some rare event, but I'm not 100% sure this is the case.

Is there anything I can do to trace back to the function that scrolls the page? I looked through all the code on the website but I cannot figure it out.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you certain the clients in question aren't using a link or bookmark that includes an anchor? (E.g., `http://example.com#foo`)

Comment: How about logging the event? https://jsfiddle.net/Sk8erPeter/Tpc3k/

Comment: Last resort, you could try to bind an adequate event listener to elements you believe are being scrolled.
`window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e){ console.log(e) })`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder There is no anchor, I am sure about it.

Comment: @AlexisFacques Probably my best bet to know what is going on. Thank you

Comment: Chrome DevTools can help. - Hit F12 to open Dev Tools - Click the Sources tab - On the right side, scroll down to "Event Listener Breakpoints", and expand tree. - Click on the events you want to monitor. Thanks.

Comment: Search for 'scroll' in the source code in developers mode and put breakpoint.